# вывод примерных-похожих вопросов при наборе текста

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, yii2

ребята, есть такая проблема, у меня есть таблица с вопросами (Questions)(заданные пользователями), мне надо их выводить по мере написание похожего вопроса, как в google или Яндекс и выводить как вариант, как мне такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно общий вопрос, не имеющий отношения к языку программирования и тем более фреймворку.

Ознакомьтесь со следующим:

- [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)
- [Алгоритмы нечеткого поиска](https://habrahabr.ru/post/115394/)
- [Теги\метки и полнотекстовый поиск](https://habrahabr.ru/post/40443/)